# Trying to start a thread in Mainactivity crashes my program

Tags: android, multithreading, android-activity, crash

I am trying to make an application that can read WiFi strength continuously and do some processing. To make the app run better thought of using threads as my app needs to monitor wifi signal variations continuously and firstly I did not use threads and It crashed as I trigger a click event to start processing wifi signals (processing code runs inside a while loop).

My MainActivity looks like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
SampleThread s;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);     
    s = new SampleThread(this);
    s.start();

}

public void changeState(View v) {
Switch sw =(Switch) findViewById(R.id.switchx);
    final boolean state = sw.isChecked();
    if (state) {
        s.on();
    } 
    else {
        s.off();
    }
}
```

Thread implementation:

```
public class SampleThread extends Thread {

boolean flag;
Context context;

public SampleThread(Activity c) {
    context =c;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    while(true){
        while(flag){
            work();             
        }
    }
}

void work(){
    //lines of code which process signal strngth
}

void on(){
    flag = true;
}
void off(){
    flag = false;
}

}
```

My thread does no work if the switch is not turned on and as it is turned on it enables a flag in the a while loop which does the actual work.

I tried a similar code with Java with swing UI and it work without any issues. I am not very savvy with android and I hope to get clarified what I am doing wrong here.

My Logcat looks like this:

```
09-14 17:46:29.902: W/dalvikvm(3632): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41c9fd40)
09-14 17:46:29.904: E/AndroidRuntime(3632): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-6876
09-14 17:46:29.904: E/AndroidRuntime(3632): Process: com.example.tet, PID: 3632
09-14 17:46:29.904: E/AndroidRuntime(3632): java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
09-14 17:46:29.904: E/AndroidRuntime(3632):     at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:200)
09-14 17:46:29.904: E/AndroidRuntime(3632):     at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:114)
09-14 17:46:29.904: E/AndroidRuntime(3632):     at com.example.tet.SampleThread.work(SampleThread.java:29)
09-14 17:46:29.904: E/AndroidRuntime(3632):     at com.example.tet.SampleThread.run(SampleThread.java:23)
```

Comment: This sounds like you are trying to create a Toast in the Thread. If so, try to comment that out.

Comment: your code has some issues, it is not thread safe and i think you use handler object in work function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

run it this way from your onCreate method

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
   s.start();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try : runOnUiThread(s); instead of s.start();

Comment: Thanks for the nice and short answer!

Answer (score 1):

To maintain the Android app maximum efficiency you shoud use either Android Serivce or Android Intent Service.
If you want to truck Wi_fi continuously i will advice you to use Android IntentSerivce class.

THERE IS LINK:
        http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

HERE I WILL DESCRIBE HOW IT WORKS AND I WILL SHOW SOME CODE:

**1) You should create new class (for example WiFiCheckerService) and extends IntentService:**

```
public class WiFiCheckerService extends IntentService
{

   //In this methos serivce receive from other class that it should start operations
   @Override
   protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) 
   {
    Thread thread = new Thread(wifiOperations_Runnable);
    thread.start();
   }

  class wifiOperations_Runnable() implements Runnable
  {
     @Override
     public void run()
     {
      while(true)
       {
         //checking wifi state or something...true/false

         broadcastState(state);
       }

     }
  }

   //broadcast wifi state to your MainActivity (where you started service):
   public broadcastState(boolean wifiState)
   {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.putExtra("WIFI_STATE", wifiState);
    sendBroadcast(intent);
   }

}
```

**2) Activity class: There you will start IntentService and receive WiFi states from it:**

```
public MainActivity extends Activity{

..attributes...


private BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {


    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
      Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
      if (bundle != null) 
        {
        boolean State = bundle.getBoolean(WIFI_STATE);
        if(State==true
       {
         ...wifi works...
       }
       else
      {
         ..doesnt work...
       }
      }
    }
  };


     ...onCreate(...)
    {
      Intent intent = new Intent(this, WiFiCheckerService.class);
      startSerivce(intent);
    }

 @Override
  protected void onResume()
 {
    super.onResume();
    registerReceiver(receiver);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onPause()
 {
    super.onPause();
    unregisterReceiver(receiver);
  }
}
```

Hope it will help, don't hestitate to ask more questions!